# GWT: which language for Server side?

Tags: gwt

Is GWT also a server-side language ?
If no, which language is it best indicate to use with GWT ?
Thanks

Comment: If by GWT you mean Google Web Toolkit, it is not a programming language. It is a set of tools that use the Java programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT is a Toolkit for building webapps written in the java language which run after compilation as javascript in the browser client. But only the stuff that is the client package is compiled into javascript. So GWT lets you work with a great IDE like Eclipse and develop and debug your stuff all on the java level. As soon as you are done GWT will compile and optimize your java code in javascript. It's a very cool and powerful idea, as writting and debugging lots of javascript can be very difficult.

As your client code is java, then it makes sense for a new projet to code also the server part in it as you deal with the same language in the same IDE. But as GWT talks with the server over HTML with JSON for transporting data almost every language can talk with an GWT frontend.

In short, if you start from scratch use Java for the server as well. If you have other server code already running which can produce JSON use this.

GWT is cool and specially designed for webapps that have to scale a lot (GWT tries to do as much on the client computer instead on the server) but it's not the easiest to learn outhere! If you do not have to scale that much may try something simpler.

Answer (score 1):

GWT is java to javascript compiler. GWT is not a language it is ajax framework. Both your client code and server code is java. However, there is some restriction on client side because 
of every object should be serializable in order to be send to the server.